# How to factor and reduce a huge determinant to simpler form? Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, determinant

So, I have learned about cofactor expansion. But the cofactor expansion I know doesn't reduce the number of rows and colums to one matrix. I usually pick a colum, multiply each element in the column by its determinant. I also know that you can factor rows, but I don't see how it could be done here. Help me, Atleast get me off step-1;

[image]

Comment: Of course in general it doesn't "reduce to one matrix." Did you not read the hint in the problem you're assigned? The important point is the zeros in your matrix, and the fact that you can choose which row or column you want to expand on.

Comment: @symplectomorphic You can read the writing? Impressive! It's so small. I could barely read the entries of the matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that if you apply the cofactor expansion along the first column we have a lot of zeroes so we only need to worry about $3$ multiplied by the determinant of a smaller matrix. Notice that there is another candidate column to which to apply the cofactor expansion in the smaller matrix (the column with the most zeroes). Continue this process. Notice that this will not be too difficult in computing since most of the expansion involves multiplication by $0$.

Comment: Thankyou very much. With your explanation, I was able to reduce and get the answer

Comment: You're welcome. Excellent I was hoping you would be able to.